# Google Cloud Build sub builds

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Is possible have multiple cloudbuild.yaml files per subdirectory?

For example:

```
my-app:
  - service1
    - cloudbuild.yaml
  - service2
    - cloudbuild.yaml
  cloudbuild.yaml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is almost correct. This will not work, because you forgot to include ".", which tells to upload and build the current directory. The correct way to include a sub/child cloudbuild.yaml would then be:

```
# Include cloudbuild sub step
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
  - 'builds'
  - 'submit'
  - '.'
  - '--config'
  - 'cloudbuild.yaml'
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, definitely! Are you trying to initialize the builds of service1 and service2 from my-app/cloudbuild.yaml?

Example of using a `meta` config to initialize other builds: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudbuild-integration-testing/blob/master/cloudbuild.meta.yaml

Here is a `cloudbuild.meta.yaml` building off of your example:

```
steps:
- id: 'build service1'
  name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['builds', 'submit', '--config service1/cloudbuild.yaml']
  waitFor: ['-'] #start in parallel
- id: 'build service2'
  name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['builds', 'submit', '--config service2/cloudbuild.yaml']
  waitFor: ['-'] # start in parallel
```